# How do I get PHPUnit to substitute a class in my test method?

Tags: unit-testing, object, mocking, phpunit

I have a class I want to test. Here is the code:

```
class MyClass
{
    function functionToTest() {

        $class = new Example();

}
```

In PHPUnit, can I use mocks/stubs to substitute for the Example class?

In my test method:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {

    function testFunctionTest() {
        $testClass = new MyClass();
        $result = $testClass->functionTest();

    }

}
```

So instead of using the actual "Example" class, can PHPUnit intervene here and use the mock to represent "new Example()" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution would be to inject an `Example` instance into `functionToTest()` method:

```
function functionToTest( Example $class )
```

Then you'll be able to mock it in your unit tests:

```
function testFunctionTest() {
    $testClass = new MyClass();
    $class = $this->getMock( 'Example' );
    $result = $testClass->functionTest( $class );

}
```

But if this approach is for some reason not an option for you, try using `set_new_overload()` function provided by the `test_helpers` extensions. See more info in [Sebastian Bergmann's blog](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/885-Stubbing-Hard-Coded-Dependencies.html).